# Looping through objects in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a number of `UIButton`s and I'm setting a custom font on them programmatically, like this:

```
Button1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myCustomFont" size:16];
Button2.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myCustomFont" size:16];
Button3.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myCustomFont" size:16];
Button4.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myCustomFont" size:16];
Button5.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myCustomFont" size:16];
Button6.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myCustomFont" size:16];
```

This code is correct and it works, but it doesn't seem like the leanest way of writing it. Is there a way to loop through these elements instead?

I had imagined something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    Button(i).titleLabel.font = etc.. // How would I get the value of 'i'?
}
```

Or is this simply a bad idea?

Comment: Whether the buttons are in an array? Or individual instances?

Comment: how often do you need to do this (in how many different places)? You could add them to an NSdictionary and the loop through to pull them back out & change properties, but it is hardly worth if to replace 6 lines of code.

Comment: It would only make sense to loop through this if the buttons are in a known order in some sort of collection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use an NSArray to iterate over:

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myCustomFont" size:16];
NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: Button1, Button2, Button3, 
                                              Button4, Button5, Button6, 
                                              nil];
for (UIButton *button in buttons) {
  button.titleLabel.font = font;
}
```

Comment: That's really neat. It's a shame I can only select one answer as correct! I'm choosing yours because it looks as though you were first.

Comment: Just remember _not to forget_ the `nil` as last argument of `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:]` to avoid undefined behaviour. It's a so called variadic argument list, which need the `nil` to determine that there are no more arguments.

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this:

```
NSMutableArray *buttons = [NSMutableArray array];
[buttons addObject: Button1];
[buttons addObject: Button2];
[buttons addObject: Button3];
[buttons addObject: Button4];
[buttons addObject: Button5];
[buttons addObject: Button6];

for (UIButton *button in buttons) {
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myCustomFont" size:16];
}
```

or

```
for (int i=1;i<7;i++) {
    SEL selector = selectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button%d", i]);
    UIButton *button = [self performSelector:selector];
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myCustomFont" size:16];
}
```

Comment: You can not add an object to `NSArray` as it is immutable (can not be modified after init). But you could use `NSMutableArray` to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess you can put all of your buttons in an array, then fast enumerate through it.

```
NSArray *buttons; 
//Put all of your buttons inhere
for (UIButton *button in buttons)
{
    button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myCustomFont" size:16];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?  currentView is the UIView that has all the buttons in it.

```
NSArray* buttonsArray = currentView.subviews;

for((UIButton*) button in buttonsArray)
{
     button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"myCustomFont" size:16];
}
```